# Is there a method to switch out a letter in a String?

Tags: java, string, indexing

I need a method that switches a letter from a specific index with another letter. Is there anything like it?

Like so:

```
String word = "test";
String letter = "e";
String secretWord = "????";
```

find the index of letter e and then find if e is in word. Then switch a "?" based on the index of the e in test.

So it would be `?e??` for secretWord.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
        string word = "test";
        char letter = 'e';
        string secretWord = "????";
        int index = word.indexOf(letter);
        if(index >= 0)
        {
         secretWord = secretWord.substring(0,index)+letter+secretWord.substring(index + 1);
         System.out.println(secretWord);
        }
```

This Code is for JAVA...... Try it

Answer (score 2):

You could use regex to search and replace any character that ISN'T `letter`:

```java
String word = "test";
String secretWord = word.replaceAll("(?i)[^e]", "?");
```

You can also add more letters you don't want replaced to the regex (this would replace every non-vowel):

```java
String secretWord = word.replaceAll("(?i)[^aeiouy]", "?");
```

Explanation of regex:

- `(?i)` means "case-insensitive".
- `^` means "NOT".
- `aeiouy` is the characters we DON'T want to match

Here's a demo of the regex replacement (just with `e`):

[**DEMO**](http://regex101.com/r/qX9rR3)

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, I'm using Java

Answer (score 0):

If you are using C# then try the Below coding.. It will help you

```
     //Declare
        string word = "test";
        char letter = 'e';
        string secretWord = "????";
        if (word.IndexOf("e") != -1)//Find the Char is found or NOT
        {
            int index = word.IndexOf(letter); //Index of the Char
            Console.WriteLine("Index of the Word E :" + word.IndexOf("e").ToString());
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(secretWord);
            sb[index] = letter; // Replacing the Char
            secretWord = sb.ToString();
            Console.WriteLine(secretWord);
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd look at the task a bit differently. We have a secret (`"test"`) and a way to display it, the result would be `"????"` or `"?e??"` if the letter `e` was provided. The sequence of `?` is not a String itself but will be generated on demand. Then we don't have to replace something in a String (what we can't do, by the way, because strings are immutable). Here's the idea written in code:

```
public class SecretWord {

    private String secret;

    public SecretWord(String secret) {
        this.secret = secret;
    }

    public String display(char c) {
        if (secret == null) {
            return "";
        }
        StringBuilder displayBuilder = new StringBuilder();
        for (char secretChar : secret.toCharArray()) {
            displayBuilder.append(secretChar == c ? c : '?');
        }
        return displayBuilder.toString();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't have enough rep to reply in a comment as yet, but you could expand on h2ooooo's post by adding in a variable to make it flexible, also:

```
String letter = "e";
String secretWord = word.replaceAll("(?i)[^" + letter + "]", "?");
```

+1, h2ooooo - tidy answer!

Westie